# How to find the mac ad of the connected devices to the cisco Router?

Tags: networking, routes, cisco

i have a cisco asa 5505 and i am controlling it with ASDM. Is there any possibilities to find the connected device's mac add?
Becuase, i wanna find and block this user, he or she has a huge network crash while working.
thanks for your nice and gently tips.
cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open ASDM, Go to Monitoring Tab. Select Interfaces, ARP Table. You will see list of all directly attached device MAC Addresses on right pane.